# Node JS createWriteStream download image

Tags: node.js

I have the following code which downloads an image from a URL and then performs some action:

```
var file                = fs.createWriteStream(local_file);
var request             = https.get(file_link, function(response) {
var request_response    = response.pipe(file);
request_response.on('finish', function(){}};
```

However when viewing the download image in a browser, I'm getting a whole page of random characters and texts, which seems like an encoding issue.

My question is, how do I download an image using Node JS with the correct encoding?$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this, using the request module.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    request = require('request');

var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
    console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);

    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
  });
};

download('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png', 'google.png', function(){
  console.log('done');
});
```

Comment: I'm still getting the issue with broken characters when viewing the image in browser.

Comment: I am able to download image from the given path. Did you try with this exact code?